# cube normal not showing on geometry nodes

Tags: texturing, geometry-nodes

so i wanted to make a pilar and used geometry nodes so that i could "randomize" the x axis, the problem is that the original cube has a texture but the copies on the node don't use the normal texture i applied to the cube

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please provide your blend file?

Comment: You should use generated or object coordinates instead of UV's . These unfortunately tend to be destroyed on instanciation in GN ([It's being worked on](https://developer.blender.org/T85962)). Please post a screenshot of your node tree as well

Comment: Thanks i did used the coordinates and it worked like a buty!!!